# Haskell data type dilemma

Tags: haskell

Hey everyone I am working on a piece of Haskell code and cannot figure out how to fix this problem.

I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Collection' with actual type `[a0]'
In the expression: [list] ++ numberToInsert
In an equation for `insert':
    insert numberToInsert (Set [list])
      | contains (Set [list]) numberToInsert == True = (Set [list])
      | otherwise = [list] ++ numberToInsert
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

Here is my code

```
data Collection = Set [Int] deriving (Show)


insert :: Int -> Collection -> Collection
insert numberToInsert (Set [list])
    |contains (Set [list]) numberToInsert == True = (Set [list])
    |otherwise = [list] ++ numberToInsert  <--- this is my problem

contains :: Collection -> Int -> Bool
contains (Set []) numberToFind = False
contains (Set (x:xs)) numberToFind
    |x == numberToFind = True
    |otherwise = contains (Set (xs)) numberToFind
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so, can you add it to your question?

Comment: When asking a question you should try to give a detailed explanation of what the problem is, and that includes the compiler error messages - we shouldn't have to guess why "this is your problem" and how to fix it. Also, you can upvote helpful  questions and answers and accept questions that satisfactorily explain your own questions. This helps organize Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have two issues with your `insert` function.

First, your two definitions of the `insert` function return different things.

```
Set [list]   -- Return type here is Collection
```

and

```
[list] ++ numberToInsert  -- Return type here is some sort of list, or [a0]
```

So first, you'll need to Make the second version return a `Collection`:

```
Set ([list] ++ numberToInsert)
```

But this is still wrong, because `numberToInsert` is not a list, and `++` concatenates two lists together, so I think you're really wanting to push it onto the front of your `[list]`.  `:` is used to push some `a` onto the front of a list of `as`  Like so:

```
Set (numberToInsert:[list])
```

Finished product:

```
insert :: Int -> Collection -> Collection
insert numberToInsert (Set [list])
    | contains (Set [list]) numberToInsert == True = (Set [list])
    | otherwise = Set (numberToInsert : [list])
```

**Update**

As you mentioned, there is one other issue I'd missed.  `list` shouldn't be wrapped in the square brackets, and here's why (in case you hadn't figured it out).

When you use the square brackets in a pattern match (the left side of the `=`), you're saying: "give me a list that looks like this, and bind it's only item to some name for use later".  So you were only expecting a list with one item, and decided to call that item `list`.

Next, you repackaged up that one item in the new list when you used it as `[list]`.

this example:

```
foo [a] = a
main = print $ foo [1]
```

would print '1'.  Passing a list of two items, however, would fail to pattern match, because you had no `foo [a, b] = ...` function defined, hence the warning:

```
main = print $ foo [1, 2]
```

So yes, removing all of the square brackets works because you are not requiring the list have only one item, but instead saying "the entire list will be called `list`", which is probably what you wanted in the first place.

Comment: I get the error non-exhaustive pattern matching, when I put the brackets around list, but when i remove the brackets it works.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.  If you hadn't figured out why, see my update.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go.

```
import Data.List (elem)

data Collection = Set [Int] deriving (Show)

insert :: Int -> Collection -> Collection
insert numberToInsert c@(Set list)
  | numberToInsert `elem` list = c
  | otherwise = Set (numberToInsert:list)
```